# A function having a pointer as its return type

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming. Can some one explain  the following function declaration? `EmpIdFen` is the class and `getInstance()` the function.

```
EmpIdGen* EmpIdGen::getInstance();
```

Comment: You are just returning a pointer to an EmpldGen object, period. With that pointer you can manipulate the object it points to.

Answer (score 0):

Use [clockwise/spiral](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) rule to read this function declaration. Using this, it means that `getInstance()` is a function returning a pointer to `EmpIdGen`. Also the `::`, is the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
    EmpIdGen*        EmpIdGen::getInstance();
  <**returnType**>    <**className**>::<**functionName**>
```

The function is returning **pointer to the same class** to which it belongs i.e EmpIdGen. As blade has commented, you can use this pointer to manipulate object it points to

Adding more to it.
Normally this kind of arrangement to retrieve object is made in implementation of **singleton** design pattern. To do this you will need to make this function static and access it using class name.
You can find more on singleton design patter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern).